# Delete button doesn't work with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, delegates, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm new to Core Data and I'm creating a simple application that displays objects. So far my program successfully saves and displays the managed objects. However, I can't get the deletion and other editing features to work on my table view. I started with an empty project and simply dragged a table view controller to the storyboard. I tested the work of my delegates and it seems that my tableview delegate is still functioning. I included an `NSLog` in my `commitEditingStyle` and the log works (when I click at the delete button). Here's my `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MPGAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entry"
                                                         inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"mpg"
                                                                   ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [request setFetchBatchSize:20];

    fetchController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                          managedObjectContext:context
                                                            sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                     cacheName:nil];
    self.tableView.delegate = nil;
    fetchController.delegate = self;
    NSError *fetchError;
    BOOL success = [fetchController performFetch:&fetchError];
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"Fetch successfull");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Fetch failed");
    }

    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = YES;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

I'm sure the problem is not the `NSFetchResultsControllerDelegate` since I pretty much copy pasted the implementations from the documentation.

Does anybody have an idea about what the issue is?

Comment: I tried disconnecting the delegates from storyboard, still no luck

Comment: Post the fetchedResultController delegate methods